# Using Javascript to Show/Hide DIV in Rails app is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, toggle

**question edited after max pleaner comment**

In an App I'm building I use this `javascript` below to show a `DIV` when the user selects the United States as a country.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  select_location = document.getElementById('order_country')
  if(select_location[select_location.selectedIndex].value == 'US')
  {
  document.getElementById('country_div').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else
  {
  document.getElementById('country_div').style.display = 'none';
  }
};

</script>
```

It shows the `DIV`at page load but if the user change the country the `DIV` won't hide. But if I change the `value == 'US'`  for an example to `value == 'CA'` the div is hiding but then if I change the country to `Canada` in the `f.country_select` in the view(form is shown below), the div remains hidden.

So my guess is that I have to somehow modify the javascript to update when the user selects a country in the `f.country_select`, but I´m not sure how I would do that.

Here is the selection form

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <%= f.label :country %>
    <%= f.country_select :country, { priority_countries: [ "US", "DE", "ES", "PT" ]}, { class: "form-control" }, {:id => "countries"  } %>
</div>
```

the html generates this ID for the `country_select` thats why I´m using the `id="order_country"`in the `javascript`above

```
<select class="form-control" name="order[country]" id="order_country">  <option value="US">United States</option>
```

This is the `div`I want to be shown/hidden

```
<div class="col-md-5" id="country_div">

 <p>delivery cost</p>

 <p><%= @cart.total_price_usd + @del_cost_usd %></p>

</div>
```

I'm not able to figure this out by myself.
It would be very nice if someone could take a look at this and advise me

thanks in advance

Comment: your `getElementById` result is evidently null. Try inspecting the generated html to see if the id exists on the form.

Comment: Hi, Your guess was right, the `country-select` seems to add a default ID called `order_country` but if I us that the div stays hidden... no matter what country I select.....

Answer (score 0):

The javascript has to be executed each time the value of the select changes. You need to call a function on select's `change` event.
Using Jquery you can write:

```
$( "#order_country" ).change(function() {
  $('#country_div').toggle();
});
```